# JsonCpp throws LogicError when exiting function

Tags: c++, jsoncpp

I have this piece of code:

```
void foo()
{
    std::string r = curlcall();
    std::string error;
    Json::CharReaderBuilder *build = new Json::CharReaderBuilder();
    Json::CharReader *read = build->newCharReader();
    Json::Value *root = new Json::Value();

    std::cout << "parse\n";
    read->parse(&r.front(), &r.back() + 1, root, &error);
    std::cout << "loop\n";
    for(auto i : *root)
    {
        //code that pulls info from each i
    }
    std::cout << "delete\n";
    delete root;
    delete read;
    delete build;
    std::cout << "end\n" << error << "\n";
}
```

When I compile and run this program it outputs:

```
parse
loop
delete
end
```

However, after this output, the program crashes here with the message:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'Json::LogicError'
      what():  in Json::Value::resolveReference(key, end): requires objectValue
    Aborted (core dumped)
```

After searching for a long time is still can't find what causes this exception to be thrown. I can't seem to be able to catch the error with a `try/catch` either.

Comment: Do you really need that many pointers? And are you sure the exception happens in this function and not in another? Have you tried to catch the exception in a debugger to locate when and where in your code it actually happens?

Comment: So, you come from the Java/C# world? this code is wrong in so many ways.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude build and root used to not be pointers but since i got that error i tried to make them pointers instead it didnt solve anything and i just left it like this. And yes straight after this function i have another text output that never happens. Havnt tried attaching a debugger on it though will try that,

Comment: @DavidHaim What is it that you consider wrong with it?

Comment: If you can't catch the exception inside of `foo`, you can `try{ foo(); }`. Then you will catch all exceptions inside of that function.

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out that im bad and didnt flush the output stream thus the text message i used to debug with didnt get printed and the error happens in the next function. Sorry for wasting peoples time.